# Livevalidation - Regex issue

Tags: javascript, regex, livevalidation

I'm using LiveValidation (http://livevalidation.com/) to validate a form on my site for a page url.
My conditions are:

- Cannot be blank
- Must start with a letter
- No spaces allowed
- Only alpha-numeric characters, dashes, and underscores

So far I have this:

```
    var formName = new LiveValidation("sitePages-name");
    formName.add(Validate.Presence);
    formName.add(Validate.Format,{ pattern: /^[a-zA-Z]/, failureMessage: "Must start with a letter." } );
    formName.add(Validate.Exclusion, {within: [' '], partialMatch: true, failureMessage: "Spaces are not allowed."});
    formName.add(Validate.Format,{ pattern:/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/, failureMessage: "Only alpha-numeric characters, dashes and underscores."})
```

The first and second conditions are met. I am struggling with the third and fourth conditions of "No spaces" and "Only alpha-numeric characters, dashes and underscores."

I tried to do the space and fourth condition by regex but it wasn't working so I just separated the spaces into the Exclusion for now.
The pattern for the fourth condition works if the character you JUST typed is not one in the regex pattern. But if you keep typing "valid" characters and have an "invalid" character previously, the error goes away and it becomes valid.

Does anyone know how to do the pattern properly to catch it if there are ANY "non-valid" characters in the input box? It would also be great if I can merge the no space condition with the pattern if possible.

Comment: You didn't anchor the last regex to the beginning of the string, so it only cares about the very end.

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_]*$/`

Comment: Thanks Michael, works perfectly now!

Comment: @ctn: you must put `-` at the first place or at the last place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*$/`.

- `[a-zA-Z]` means letter.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]` means letter, digit, dash or underscore.
- `*` means repeat 0 or more times
- `^` is the start of the string
- `$` is the end of the string

This reads out as: At the start of the string, match a latter, then match zero or more letters, digits or underscore characters, then match the end of the string.

Comment: This works except for the missing dash like ctn mentioned! But that's an easy fix. Thanks!

Comment: @Guest I'm glad it helped. If it helped you consider watching [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkluES9Rvak), we've seen good results with it helping new comers with regex in the regex chat room here in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Not having used that plug-in, I take it that subsequent validations added via `add` are handled in order.

In which case:

```
var formName = new LiveValidation("sitePages-name");
// Must be present
formName.add(Validate.Presence);
// Must start with A-Z or a-z
formName.add(Validate.Format,{ pattern: /^[a-zA-Z]/, failureMessage: "Must start with a letter." } );
// Must only have A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _, or -
formName.add(Validate.Format,{ pattern:/.[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+$/, failureMessage: "Only alpha-numeric characters, dashes and underscores."})
```

I haven't put a rule in for spaces because it's covered by the third rule, requiring `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, `_`, and `-`.

Above I'm assuming you want to be as specific as you reasonably can be in the error message. Because it *can* be done in a single step:

```
formName.add(Validate.Format,{ pattern: /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*$/, failureMessage: "Must start with a letter and consist only of alphanumerics, underscores, or dash characters" } );
```

(That assumes single-character entries are allowed. If you require at least two characers, change `*` to `+`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z][\w-]*$/
```

Comment: Please add some kind of explanation as to why you think this regex will work.

Comment: @rgettman: Sure, but i think "Guest" is not interested by, as you can see.