# Controlling users input for feet and inches

Tags: html, regex, masking

How can you prefill an input box with 0'00" Then as the user starts typing it prefills in those 0's? like 12'02". I want the left side of the " ' " to be able to reach 2000 and the right side of the " ' " to only be able to reach 11.

```
<label for="ft">Feet:</label>
<input type="text" name="ft" id="ft">
```

I am not sure if I would need a RegEx or a mask or what... Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Maybe RegEx?
`"[1-2000]'(0[0-9]|1[0-1])"""` Or something like that?

Comment: Why not use separate `<input>`s? (Or use metric. )

Comment: I wanted to :) that's how I had it set up and of course I was told I must change it to be easier on the user to only fill in one textbox =(

Comment: I argued it and said its not as easy as it sounds but was sent away to come up with this solution :/

Comment: Are you going to validate upon form submit, or live? Initial pre-filling can easily be done with ` value="0'00&quot;"`, but validation is a different thing.

Comment: I was going to have it live and use the regex for the validation. I cant really use the attribute that way because it is set to a session variable already

Comment: well actually id probably have to make it live with the regex also

Comment: is it possible to use that regex to set up a mask as well then maybe?

Comment: Please check this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225292/livevalidation-regex-issue.

Comment: right no I get that but what I cant figure out is the first portion of my question prefilling the value If I already have is set up as a session variable `value ="#form.ft#"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should suffice.

```
^([1-2]?[0-9]{1,3})\'([0-9]|[0-1]{2})\"$
```

https://regex101.com/r/xD3lC3/3

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Using what technologies? With `html5`, perhaps the pattern attribute? http://html5pattern.com/

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by "Make an input display like that". Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562862/controlling-users-input-for-feet-and-inches/29563135?noredirect=1#comment47275342_29562862)

Comment: @ZaneZ see: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ - You will need Javascript to do this. Unsure if it can be done with HTML5.

Comment: I am having a problem still with this reg ex can you help real quick?

Comment: for inches it needs to be able do 10 or 11

Comment: but also 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09

Comment: yours is set up to only do singles like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,